# Output HTML form to .txt file

Tags: php, html

So I have tried many solutions, many different ways of writing this including reading online and here. This is something so simple, yet I have no idea what I'm doing wrong!

Here is a snippet of the form:

```
<form class="form-inline signup signup-form" role="form" action="submit-email.php" method="POST"> 
 <div class="form-group">
  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="Email1" name="Email1" placeholder="Enter your email address">
 </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-theme" value="Save Email">Get notified!</button>
</form>
```

and the 'submit-email.php'.

```
<?php
/**
 * Trying to write the contents of the HTML form to .txt
 */
 error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// All the values of the HTML form are securely stored in the array $v:
$v = array_map('trim', filter_input_array(INPUT_POST));

// Text formatting:
$text = '-- START ' . date('c') . ' --\n'
    . "User email:{$v['email']}\n";

// Following lines of code open, write, and close your connection
// to a text file:
$file = 'emails.txt';
$fp = fopen($file, 'w');
fwrite($handle, $text);
fclose($fp);
```

One of the other attempts:

```
<?php
$file = 'emails.txt'
$email = $_POST['Email1'];
$fp = fopen("emails.txt", "a");
$savestring = $email . "\n";
fwrite($fp, $savestring);
fclose($fp);
echo "<h1>Thank you, we will be in touch as soon as possible!</h1>";
```

> still need to add a javascript popup/alert instead of just echo. But if someone can help with the file output at least - it would be greatly appreciated!

Here are the errors - not reading the 'email' variable even if I set it (as if it's not POST-ing properly:

```
Notice: Undefined index: email in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/apa_dev/submit-email.php on line 12

Warning: fopen(emails.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/apa_dev/submit-email.php on line 17

Notice: Undefined variable: handle in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/apa_dev/submit-email.php on line 18

Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/apa_dev/submit-email.php on line 18

Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/apa_dev/submit-email.php on line 19
```

Keeping in mind I have tried many different ways to write this.

Comment: `file_put_contents( 'emails.txt', implode( PHP_EOL, $_POST ) );` ?

Comment: What happens? Doesn't it save the email to file? Try check the errors after opening the file.

Comment: What exactly isnt working as expected ? No output ? no file written ? blank page ? ...

Comment: there are more questions in comments than in the question itself.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to tag as PHP - let me fix that! It isn't outputting to the file, or creating it. I tried to make it myself, and set permissions but to no avail thus far.

Have added the output errors to the OP. Thanks guys!

Comment: RamRaider - What do I do with this? Sorry, I am kinda lost here.

Comment: The error messages seem to relate to the first version of the script. You are using `$v['email']` where it should be `$v['Email1']`. This explains the first errormessage. You have no access to the file, that is the second errormessage. Then you use `$handle` while you defined `$fp`, there is no variable named `handle`. That is the third errormessage. The others are a result of the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your html is ok.
For your php, your second approach is better and it works ok.
You just have a missing semicolon(;) at the end of line 2

```
$file = 'emails.txt' <--- missing semicolon(;)
```

Note: you are not using the variable $file in line 4

But there is simpler solution to you code (same approach).

To write to a file you can use "file_put_contents"
It does exactly the same as these three functions: fopen(), fwrite() and fclose().

And because you want to keep writing at the end of the file, just add the FILE_APPEND parameter.

```
<?php
$file = 'emails.txt';
$email = $_POST['Email1'];
$data = "email: $email , whatever, more form data  "; // here you can format your string for evry line of data; no need to put the new line here
file_put_contents($file, $data ."\n",FILE_APPEND); // new line is added here
echo "<h1>Thank you, we will be in touch as soon as possible!</h1>";
?>
```

Comment: All working! Thank you so much for that, I knew the permissions were an issue - I tried heaps of ways but wasn't sure how to use "file_put_contents" properly, getting back into the rhythym of all of this.. 

Should be easy enough to add a popup now! Cheers again!

Comment: Done, I appreciate it. :)